# Solving $ x - a = \sqrt{(x-a)^2 + b^2} $ for $x$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Given the following equation:

$$
x - a = \sqrt{(x-a)^2 + b^2}
$$

Is there any way to move $x$ to one side and everything else to the other side?

Comment: Try squaring both sides.

Comment: no; you can square both sides. If your two sides are equal, the squares are equal. However, for nonzero $b$ that is impossible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Square both sides and you would only have $b^{2} = 0$, so a solution exists if $b = 0$

As the square root must be greater than zero, then the LHS $\geq 0$ so, $x-a \geq 0$

So $x \geq a$ and your solution set would then be $\left \{(x,a,b) | x \geq a, b = 0 \right\}$

Answer (score 1):

Apply this rule :

- If $A=\sqrt B$, then

$$\begin{cases} A^2=B \\B≥0\\A≥0\end{cases} $$